# insert in a batch if row does not exists using Mybatis

Tags: java, postgresql, mybatis, bulkinsert

I am able to insert in a batch using Java-Mybatis-Postgresql.

```
@Insert({ "<script>",
        "insert into test (demo_id,demo_name)",
        "values ", "<foreach  collection='recordList' item='record' separator=','>",
        "(#{record.demoId},#{record.demoName})",
        "</foreach>", "</script>" })
public Integer insertBatch(@Param("recordList") List<RestDemo> recordList);
```

how to insert in a batch if row does not exists using Mybatis(Postgresql)?

Comment: PostgreSQL 9.5+ supports [INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What%27s_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.5#INSERT_..._ON_CONFLICT_DO_NOTHING.2FUPDATE_.28.22UPSERT.22.29).

Comment: @ave yes, but how to the same using Mybatis.

Comment: Remove `IGNORE` and add `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` after `</foreach>`, I presume. If it didn't work, please explain how it didn't work in the question.